# Fast import whole MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have MySQL table that has many rows (3.405.924) and 5 columns. The table changes very rarely. When I import the whole table using python, R or some other programming language it takes cca 5 minutes to import it. Is there a way to make this import faster? I read somewhere that it is possible to use the cache, but I can't find any example for MySQL.

I am not providing the code example because the MySQL code is just `SELECT * FROM table_name`, but the question is how to make it faster when importing the whole table (using cpanel).

Comment: Who cares? You're doing it just once, right?

Comment: What format does imported data have? .SQL? .CSV?

Comment: @Strawberry Actually I am not doing it only once. I am importing it many times.

Comment: @Akina, data is a table in cpanel. I know I can import it faster if I save it localy as hdf5 file, but I am curious is it possible to import it faster using mysql.

Comment: You're repeatedly importing an essentially static table. That doesn't seem to make much sense

Comment: @Strawberry, it is not fully static, it is changed once a week.

Comment: You do not need a database if you import all at once.

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff, what do you recommend than. Is there some cheap cloud solution for importing hdf5 files (I think they are tha fastest for tabular data)?

Comment: Could you do the work in the database? Or some work to reduce how much data you need to download?

Comment: I can;t do the work in database unfortunatelly

Comment: Are you using `load data infile`?  That is usually the fastest method.  Alternatively, keep a safe copy of the data on your server and just copy over the master copy when you need a new copy.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, this load data to database, but I want to load whole table from dtabase to local memory with python/R in fast way.

Answer (score 0):

There are [ton of techniques](https://www.laymansmag.com/how-to-make-mysql-database-faster/) that can be used to make MySQL queries run faster, for example:

- Select only needed rows
- Use InnoDB instead of MyISAM

I would recommend this [post](https://www.laymansmag.com/how-to-make-mysql-database-faster/) for some other techniques that can be implemented